# how to get the context in dialogFragment when get imei info

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, contextmenu

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_reg_dialog, null);
    TextView tvIMEI = null;

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Activer la Version");
    registerKey = view.findViewById(R.id.regiter_key);
    tvIMEI = view.findViewById(R.id.tvIMEI);
    String sIMEI;
    sIMEI = getUniqueIMEIId(getContext(this));
    tvIMEI.setText(sIMEI);
    return builder.create();
}
```

getUniqueIMEIID not abel `this` context , when I call `getContext(this)` give error[image from android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD7rM.png)

```
public static String getUniqueIMEIId(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) 
     context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     ...
     String imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    ...
}
```

Comment: what is your getUniqueIMEIId method? is it your own method or third library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the `dialogFragment` to create dialog, and the `getUniqueIMEIId` like this:

```
public static String getUniqueIMEIId(Context context) {
    try {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {          
            return "";
        }
        String imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        Log.e("imei", "=" + imei);
        if (imei != null && !imei.isEmpty()) {
            return imei;
        } else {
            return android.os.Build.SERIAL;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "not_found";
}
```

`getContext()` is .

> Return the Context this fragment is currently associated with
>   but the `getUniqueIMEIId` method needs the context

`getActivity()` is

> Return the FragmentActivity this fragment is currently associated with. May return null if the fragment is associated with a Context instead

in main situation they are the same. and we only need `context`. so I suggested you use the `getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the error? Is it showing that Context is expected but a Dialog was passed?

If yes you can just use the getActivity() method that you used above to get access to the context.

So just call

```
sIMEI = getUniqueIMEIId(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `getContext(this)` with `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` and it should work.